# How to add plugin to blog

Tags: plugins

I just created a new blog and I'd like to add a plug-in to the blog.

I am following [this tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins_Add_New_Screen) on how to do it, but on my admin screen there is no "Plugins" option (under "Appearance").

What am I doing wrong?  What can I do to get my desired plugin for my blog?

Comment: By _created_ do you mean you installed WordPress **.org** on your hosting account or you had registered for a blog at WordPress **.com** service? Latter does not support user-installed plugins.

Comment: Do you host your own blog (did you download the software and install it yourself)? Or is this blog hosted on WordPress.com?

Comment: This blog is hosted on WordPress.com.

Comment: wordpress.com administration questions are off topic here. They have their own support forum where you may get better help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add plugins on wordpress.com, only on self-hosted sites.